# Package [listings]: Specify start/end line of code without line numbers

Tags: listings, strings

I often use the `\lstinputlisting` command from the [`listings`](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) package
to import whole or portions of standalone `<codingLanguage>` code files into my documents.

**Problem**

When I want to insert an except from the whole `<codingLanguage>` script,
I use:

```
\lstinputlisting[caption     = {Caption}, 
                 label       = COD:script, 
                 firstline   = 7740, 
                 firstnumber = 7740, 
                 lastline    = 7766
                ]
                {\main/Scripts/script.m}
```

in which case, I am specifying by line number.

The problem is that edits to that code shift the line numbers,
making the document latex code obsolete and requiring manual fixing.

I read through the `listings` package manual, but did not find anything.
I admit that I may have read the answer and not known it was the answer.

**Desired Resolution**:

How can I start and stop excepts with less volatile parameters?

I would much prefer to place some form of marker in the `<codingLanguage>` code
for which the latex code `\lstinputlistings` could search,
(and I'd need to be able to have multiple unique markers).

Comment: See section **6.7 Arbitrary `linerange` markers** of the [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf).

Comment: @Werner I saw this section in my first run-through.  I had concerns since it was listed as `experimental` and I wondered if anything stable was already in place.  Do prefixes and suffixes exist only such that a repeating prefix/suffix does not need to be entered in each listing command? Is it possible to show the prefix line without the suffix line? How would I set `firstlinenumber` to the correct line without knowing the firstlinenumber. Should these be separate questions?

Comment: @Werner Edited to add listings link.  Didn't mean to undo submission to close.

Comment: @kando, do the answers to the linked question address your own? It really seems like an exact duplicate.

Comment: @Werner The linked question states that I can use text in place of line numbers. I will assume that prefixes/suffixes are not necessary, but are convenient. It is not addressed whether `firstline` and `lastline` may be used in place of `linerange`.  It is not addressed what to do with `firstlinenumber`. I will test whether the `firstlinenumber` is automatically set.